# ReferenceError:until is not defined selenium javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium

I'm trying to run a web automation code using javascript using selenium. unfortunately whenever I use the driver.wait()function to access the password input field of google sign in, even I use correct css selector inside the function, my console throws this error  ReferenceError : until is not defined. Any help would be appreciated

This is my code :

[My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfyf0.png)

Comment: there is a typo error in your code, until vs util

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not share screenshots of your code. Instead, add it into the question and mark as code.

Comment: Please read [ask].